# tkinter screenshot with mss not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot, tkinter-canvas, python-mss

essentially the problem is: I want to take a screenshot of my tkinter canvas.
Unfortunately I am not able to understand PIL, so don't gaslight me with Pillow or ImageGrab please.

```
from mss import mss

def test_shot(self):
    with mss() as sct:
        filename = sct.shot(mon=1, output="E:/project/screenshots/test_output.png")
```

So this actually takes a screenshot of the whole screen, in a sense that is suboptimal and blunt, But it doesn't screenshot the tkinter gui(root:frame:canvas;labels,...) and instead screenshots what is behind my tkinter gui(the code in idle and also console).

So basically my questions are:
1st Is there a way to take screenshot of the whole canvas or parts of it?
2nd Why does the screenshot show everything except my program?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWXMo.png)

Edit:
so this is how I call the function for testing purposes:
[shortened code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH7Kg.png)

Edit 2:
whenever I use mytk.update() or canvas/self.graphs.update() , it gets transparent [test output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVqBj.png)

Comment: The only way that code could behave as you describe is if it were called *before* your GUI window was actually opened.  If it was supposed to be called by clicking a Button - perhaps you did `command=test_shot()` (an immediate call to the function) rather than `command=test_shot` (specifying a function to be called when the Button is clicked)?

Comment: where do you run `test_shot()`? It seems you use it in wrong way. maybe you run it before `tkinter` display window. `mainloop()` starts code and it displays window.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you could use `Tk.update()` (or maybe even `after`) to wait for Tk to process events (e.g. creating and laying out windows) before taking your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.grab()` to capture part of the screen:

```py
from mss import mss, tools

...

def test_shot(self):
    # self.graphs is the canvas object
    # make sure it is updated
    self.graphs.update()
    with mss() as sct:
        monitor = {
            "top": self.graphs.winfo_rooty(),
            "left": self.graphs.winfo_rootx(),
            "width": self.graphs.winfo_width(),
            "height": self.graphs.winfo_height(),
            "mon": 1
        }
        # grab the image of the specified region
        img = sct.grab(monitor)
        # save the image to file
        tools.to_png(img.rgb, img.size, output="test_output.png")
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. When I run this I get a semi-transparent screenhot, where you can see the screen and the desktop(something is off about "opacity"), can you tell me why?

Comment: I don't know why because it works fine in my Windows 11 with Python 3.12.0 and mss 9.0.1.